# Passing custom arguments to $resource and transformResponse

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource

Due to some extraordinary circumstances I am currently busy with creating a client-only, server-less app using AngularJS. Its single purpose (for the moment) is to read a .json file, containing an array of *Activity* objects as follows:

```
[{
    "id": "sta",
    "title": "IT Strategy & Governance",
    "type": "management",
    "order": 1
},
{
    "id": "por",
    "title": "Portfolio Management",
    "type": "management",
    "order": 2
},
{
    "id": "org",
    "title": "Organization & Process Management",
    "type": "management",
    "order": 3
}]
```

Please keep in mind that this file is static and not generated by any kind of backend. I would now like to achieve to objectives.

**Objective 1** is to load this complete list of objects. I accomplish this using an Angular $resource as follows, and it works beautifully:

Service:

```
pexServices.factory('Activities', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/activities.json', {});
});
```

Controller:

```
pexControllers.controller('ActivityCtrl',
    function($scope, Activities) {
        $scope.activities = Activities.query();
    }
);
```

**Objective 2** is to get one individual record out of this array, selecting it via its ID. As before, the data shall be pulled out of the one, big data file including all data objects.

My idea is too add a custom *get* function to the $resource already introduced above and include some *transformResponse* code that extracts the requested element:

```
pexServices.factory('Activities', function($resource) {
    return $resource('data/activities.json', {}, {
        get: {
        method: "GET",
        transformResponse: function(rawData, headersGetter) {
            var jsonData = jQuery.parseJSON(rawData);
            var requestedObject = jsonData.filter(function(activity) {
                return activity.id == "THEREQUESTEDID";
            });
            return requestedObject.shift();
        }
    }
    });
});
```

This works great, but only as long as I hard code the requested ID at *THEREQUESTEDID*. However, I obviously want to pass a variable parameter into the get function in order to pull the needed object, like this:

```
$scope.activity = Activities.get({activityId: "sta"});
```

Unfortunately, this is the point where I have been stuck for a while now. How do I enable a parameter to pass all the way from my controller to the *transformResponse* function, where I can use it to filter the array?

As said before, the file itself is static and won't react to any parameters, so I need to do the filtering manually on the client.

Thanks a lot for your support and for keeping in mind my limited JS skills. :-)

(In case you have another entirely different solution to my problem in mind, please feel free to share it as well! This is just my first shot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not this way! You need to create a service with methods and wrap your resource object inside it. The service would be something like this

```
pexServices.factory('Activities', function ($resource) {
    var service = {};
    var cachedActivities = [];
    service.getAll = function () {
        cachedActivities = $resource('data/activities.json', {});
        return cacheActivities;
    }
    service.getActivity = function (id) {
        var requestedObject = jsonData.filter(function (activity) {
            return cachedActivities.id == id;
        });
        return requestedObject.shift();
    }
    return service;
});
```

Now your service has 2 methods, one for list and one for specific activity. Also the activities retrieved from server are cached in a local variable. The only issue here is that `getActivity` will only work if you call `getAll` first. If you want to fix it, move to a promise based approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I will consider it again in detail as soon as my JS skills have advanced a bit further!